# Подскажите как скорректировать декоратор python

Tags: python, декоратор

Есть такая задача:

Напишите декоратор `@takes`, который будет проверять правильность типов входных аргументов функции, которая принимает лишь позиционные аргументы.
Декоратор принимает на вход типы аргументов и декорирует функцию таким образом, что если хотя бы один из аргументов имеет неверный тип, то декорированная функция не исполняется и выводится сообщение `"ERROR!"`.

Если количество аргументов функции и количество переданных типов разное:
аргументов больше, чем типов - ошибку генерировать не нужно (возможно, точные типы данных известны только для первых аргументов, их как раз и надо проверить)
типов больше, чем аргументов - ошибка, если переданные аргументы не подходят под соответствующие им по порядку типы (декоратор может быть применен к функциям с переменным числом аргументов).
Декоратор должен вести себя порядочно, то есть не должен затирать основные аргументы функции (`__name__`, `__doc__`, `__module__`).

у меня вообще капитальная беда с декораторами, поэтому все до чего удалось дойти пока выглядит так:

```
import inspect

# decorator

def takes(func):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        for i in args, kwargs:
            if i.kind != i.POSITIONAL_ONLY:
                print('ERROR!')
            else:
                func(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner

@takes    
def f(1, '1'):
    print('OKAY')
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "/var/folders/pd/y35txfqs6wz0h0q_6kbx9y040000gn/T/ipykernel_6267/3786218546.py", line 15
    def f(1, '1'):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Не понимаю, что конкретно не так, помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот такой код после комментария

```
# decorator

def takes(func):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            print('ERROR!')
        func(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner

@takes 
def fun(*args,**kwargs):
    print('OKAY')

fun(1, '1')
```

Теперь ошибка исчезла , но ответ некорректный. При попытке fun(1,1) тоже выйдет OKAY, хотя должно быть ERROR!

Comment: `def f(1, '1'):` - при объявлении функции нужно имена параметров указывать, а не конкретные значения. Вы скрестили объявление функции и вызов. По декоратору - функцию нужно вызывать только когда все уже проверено, после цикла. Чтобы не вызывалось при наличии ошибок, нужно после печати ошибки из inner выйти через return.

Comment: Ну и в принципе проверить, что есть только позиционные аргументы можно просто проверив, что kwargs пустой (условно, `if kwargs: print("error")`)

Comment: Спасибо, пойду пробовать

Comment: "При попытке fun(1,1) тоже выйдет OKAY, хотя должно быть ERROR!" - ну значит нужно return делать при ошибке, а не просто выводить и продолжать выполнение. Либо выполнение функции делать в else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import functools

def type_dec(*type_args):
    type_args_len = len(type_args)
    def dec(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            assert len(args) >= type_args_len, f'типов({type_args_len} шт.) больше, чем аргументов({len(args)} шт.)'
            for t, a in zip(type_args, args):
                if type(a) != t:
                    raise TypeError(f"ERROR! аргумент `{a}` имеет неверный тип {type(a).__name__}, а должен быть {t.__name__}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return dec

@type_dec(int, str)
def get_result_1(a, b, c):
    """test"""
    return 'ok'

@type_dec(str, str, str)
def get_result_2(a):
    return 'ok'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # >>> get_result test __main__
    print(get_result_1.__name__, get_result_1.__doc__, get_result_1.__module__, )
    # >>> 'ok'
    print(get_result_1(1, '2', 3))
    # >>> TypeError: ERROR! аргумент `2` имеет неверный тип int, а должен быть str
    print(get_result_1(1, 2, 3))
    # >>> AssertionError: типов(3 шт.) больше, чем аргументов(1 шт.)
    print(get_result_2(1))
```